# Loading/displaying an image with javascript and getting % downloaded

Tags: php, javascript, html

So some background: what I'm doing, is creating a gallery that shows thumbnails of all the pictures in a server directory dynamically (it caches the thumbnails, don't worry). When a user clicks on a thumbnail, a loading gif is displayed until the image is ready, and then the image displayed. The actual pictures are very large in size and might take a considerable amount of time to download to a users computer.

What I would like to do, is show a percentage of the picture that is downloaded while the loading gif is playing.

I realize there are other questions like this, and from what research I've done so far, I also realize this might not be able to be accomplished without some server-side tricks.

From what I have come across in the last little bit, I've gathered (and I could be wrong, so please correct me if I am) is that the client-side code, knows how many bytes are received, but not how large the file is.

So is there a possible configuration using some php/javascript tricks, so that the client side javascript can load an image from a web-server directory and be able to calculate downloaded percentage?

Possibly the php code sending an extra header to the client with file size or something? Or even opening a second request to the web server for file size? How could you get the currently downloaded bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XMLHttpRequest2`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) to load the data and hook onto the progress events. The loaded data is turned into base64 and added to a Data URI. Once loading has finished you can assign a new image source to the constructed URI.

More info can be found here: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/